# Add/change multipart_params parameter when uploading post image

Tags: uploads, media, plupload

I'm working on plugin that optionally manipulates uploaded content (images). I managed to add some additional fields on "Insert media" popup under "Drop files anywhere to upload" text, but I need to send those parameters with file content to `async-upload.php` when uploading.

Pre WP v3.3, I've been using this to achive desired results:

```
jQuery('input:text[name="custom_text"]').keyup(function() {
    wpUploaderInit.multipart_params.custom_text = jQuery(this).val(); 
});
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant code, working or not?

Comment: Pre WP v3.3 I've been using this to achive desired results:
`jQuery('input:text[name="custom_text"]').keyup(function() {
    wpUploaderInit.multipart_params.custom_text = jQuery(this).val();
});`

Comment: Please [edit] the code into the question rather than post it as a comment, but that isn't really enough code. There isn't enough context. Can you post enough that the problem can be duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

**To send a customer data to the server, do the following**

```
customFileFrame.uploader.options.uploader.params.yourCustomProperty = 'yourCustomValue';
```

Where:

```
yourCustomProperty - parameter name
yourCustomValue - parameter value
```

**processing data from the server**

```
add_action('add_attachment', array($this, 'addAttachmentParama'));
```

---

```
public function addAttachmentParama($post_id){
    if (isset($_REQUEST['yourCustomProperty']) && isset($_REQUEST['action']) && 'upload-attachment' == $_REQUEST['action']) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'yourCustomProperty', $_REQUEST['yourCustomProperty']);
     }
 }
```

**Mini Plugin for example**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: ExsempleDimetrodonMediaUploader
Version: 0.0.1
Author: Dimetrodon
License: GPLv2 or later
*/

class ExsempleDimetrodonMediaUploader
{
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Get (and instantiate, if necessary) the instance of the class
     *
     * @static
     * @return ExsempleDimetrodonMediaUploader
     */
    public static function get_instance(){
        if (!is_a(self::$instance, __CLASS__)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __clone(){}

    private function __construct(){
        add_shortcode('ExsempleDimetrodonMediaUploader', array($this, 'MediaUploader'));
        add_action('add_attachment', array($this, 'addAttachmentParama'));
    }

    public function addAttachmentParama($post_id){
        if (isset($_REQUEST['yourCustomProperty']) && isset($_REQUEST['action']) && 'upload-attachment' == $_REQUEST['action']) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'yourCustomProperty', $_REQUEST['yourCustomProperty']);
        }
    }

    public function MediaUploader()
    {
        wp_enqueue_media();
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <img id="image">
        <button class="image-uploader">Image Uploader</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function ($) {
                var customFileFrame;
                $(document).on('click', '.image-uploader', function (event) {
                    if (typeof(customFileFrame) !== "undefined") {
                        customFileFrame.close();
                    }

                    //Create WP media frame.
                    customFileFrame = wp.media.frames.customHeader = wp.media({
                        //Title of media manager frame
                        title: "Select Image",
                        library: {
                            type: 'image'
                        },
                        button: {
                            text: "Select Image"
                        },
                        multiple: false
                    });

                    //Sending of a custom parameters to the server
                    customFileFrame.uploader.options.uploader.params.yourCustomProperty = 'yourCustomValue';

                    //callback for selected image
                    customFileFrame.on('select', function () {
                        var attachment = customFileFrame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                        $('#image').attr('src', attachment.url);
                        //do something with attachment variable, for example attachment.filename
                        //Object:
                        //attachment.alt - image alt
                        //attachment.alt - image alt
                        //attachment.url
                        //attachment.author - author id
                        //attachment.caption
                        //attachment.dateFormatted - date of image uploaded
                        //attachment.description
                        //attachment.editLink - edit link of media
                        //attachment.filename
                        //attachment.height
                        //attachment.icon - don't know WTF?))
                        //attachment.id - id of attachment
                        //attachment.link - public link of attachment, for example ""http://example.com/?attachment_id=115""
                        //attachment.menuOrder
                        //attachment.mime - mime type, for example image/jpeg"
                        //attachment.name - name of attachment file, for example "my-image"
                        //attachment.status - usual is "inherit"
                        //attachment.subtype - "jpeg" if is "jpg"
                        //attachment.title
                        //attachment.type - "image"
                        //attachment.uploadedTo
                        //attachment.url - http url of image, for example "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/my-image.jpg"
                        //attachment.width
                    });

                    //Open modal
                    customFileFrame.open();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
ExsempleDimetrodonMediaUploader::get_instance();
```

Comment: Answers should be more than a code snippet. Please file an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/210664/edit) and explain why this would work.

Comment: What you have posted makes no sense, is this a question, comment or an answer. What does the code do, how does it work, etc etc....

Comment: Please expand upon this answer. As is, it is meaningless to anyone who doesn't already know what they are doing. In fact, it doesn't make sense to people who do know what they are doing (@PieterGoosen is no slouch, nor am I).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the explanations. I roll up in the vanity of vanities

Comment: My question is here: ( https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289648/how-to-set-additional-parameter-in-wp-media ). Your answer works. Thank you. But this still doesn't work if I just click open media dialog. The parameter did not send.
However it was send to upload file hooks correctly.

Do you have any suggestion about send it to browse dialog?

Comment: It works! Thanks man... I've been trying to extend this functionality in various ways but couldn't get across it. Just glad I found this.

Comment: This works great in conjunction with the `upload_dir` filter hook as well.