# How to set additional parameter in wp.media?

Tags: media, media-modal

I have this code.

```
$('.custom-browse-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var wpMedia = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        'library': {
            type: 'image'
        },
        'multiple': true
    });
    wpMedia.open()
        .on('select', function(e) {
            var uploaded_image = wpMedia.state().get('selection').toJSON();
            // already done with select.
            console.log(uploaded_image);
        });
});
```

In ajax request there are these parameters in the method POST:

```
action:query-attachments
post_id:0
query[post_mime_type]:image
query[orderby]:date
query[order]:DESC
query[posts_per_page]:40
query[paged]:1
```

I want to add something more fore checking and hooks. Example: `my_filtered_user_id=3` OR `media_width_eqm=1000`

How to add these things in wp.media?

**Update:**
Now I am able to send parameter to upload hooks using [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/210664/41315).
However I still unable to send GET or POST data to browse media hooks (`ajax_query_attachments_args`) using that answer.

```
$('.custom-browse-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var wpMedia = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        'library': {
            type: 'image'
        },
        'multiple': true
    });
    wpMedia.uploader.options.uploader.params.my_filtered_user_id = 3;
    wpMedia.open()
        .on('select', function(e) {
            var uploaded_image = wpMedia.state().get('selection').toJSON();
            // already done with select.
            console.log(uploaded_image);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been searching for this answer too and found it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451531/how-to-display-filtered-media-elements-in-wordpress-media-uploader).  You just need to add a property to the library object:

```
var wpMedia = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    'library': {
        type: 'image',
        custom_var: 'webhead'
    },
    'multiple': true
});
```

Then in PHP you can see the custom variable in the `ajax_query_attachments_args` hook like so:

```
function webhead_ajax_query_attachments_args() {
    var_dump($_REQUEST['query']['custom_var']);
    exit;
}
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'webhead_ajax_query_attachments_args' );
```