# Filter media library by custom postmeta

Tags: media-library

I am using ACF plugin.

I created a select field `custom_select` on ACF that is included to every attachment.

ACF writes these values in the postmeta table.

I now want to filter my attachments in my media library by this field `custom_select`.

I found many articles on including taxonomies but none for postmeta.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter medias from the Media Uploader (wp.media) modal with a post meta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/357236/filter-medias-from-the-media-uploader-wp-media-modal-with-a-post-meta)

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement the following:

1. Change the admin UI to include my custom filters

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_media', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script('media-library-taxonomy-filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom-media-filter.js', array('media-editor', 'media-views'));
});
```

2. In the custom-media-filter.js I am appending the custom select HTML and every time my custom select is changed, add the query parameters in the URL and redirect with this parameter and value

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.filter-items').append('<select class="form-select" aria-label="Custom filter document_category" id="page-document_category"><option>-Choose-</option><option value="document">Document</option><option value="template">Template</option></select>');
    jQuery('#page-document_category').change(function (e) {
        insertParam('document_category', this.value)
    });
    // insert and redirect with new value
    function insertParam(key, value) {
        key = encodeURIComponent(key);
        value = encodeURIComponent(value);
        // remove all other parameters
        var kvp = [];
        kvp.push(key + '=' + value);
        document.location.search = params;
    }

});
```

3. Add action in my functions.php binding to the `pre_get_posts`

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_filter');
```

and create my custom function `my_custom_filter` that changes the meta query only when my custom filters are sent to the URL

```php
if (!function_exists('my_custom_filter')) {
    function my_custom_filter($wp_query_obj)
    {
        $url_query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        $params = array();
        foreach ($url_query as $param) {
            if (isset($param) && $param[0] !== '') {
                // prevent notice on explode() if $param has no '='
                if (strpos($param, '=') === false) $param += '=';

                list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
                $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
                urldecode_deep($params);
            }
        }
        $found = false;
        if (isset($params['document_category'])) {
            $meta_key = 'document_category';
            $meta_value = $params['document_category'][0];
            $found = true;
        }

        // here i can add more filters

        // else if ($params['document_type']) {
        //    $meta_key = 'document_type';
        //    $meta_value = $params['document_type'][0];
        //    $found = true;
        // }
 
        if ($found) {
            $meta_query = array(
                array(
                    'key'     => $meta_key,
                    'value'   => $meta_value,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            );
            $wp_query_obj->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
            $wp_query_obj->set('orderby',    'meta_value_num');
            $wp_query_obj->set('order',      'ASC');
        }
        return;
    }
}
```